# About surface of integral of type one

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits, analysis

Compute F(x,y,z,t)=$\iint _Sf(\xi ,\eta ,\zeta) dS$,S is surface
$$(\xi -x)^2+(\eta-y)^2+(\zeta-z)^2=t^2$$,suppose $ r^2={x^2+y^2+z^2}>a^2>0$

$f(\xi ,\eta ,\zeta)=1$
,when $\xi^ 2+\eta ^2+\zeta ^2<a^2$,

$f=0$ ,             when $\\ \xi^ 2+\eta ^2+\zeta ^2\ge a^2$

My attempt.

If r$\ge t+a$,then the integral is zero,but when r$<t+a$ ,the integral is difficult .i think maybe I should rotate the Rectangular Coordinates.

Comment: ooyes thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation is rotation symmetric with respect to the axis through $O=(0,0,0)$ and $P=(x,y,z)$. It follows that the value $F(x,y,z,t)$ depends only on $a$,  $r>a$, and $t$. You may assume $P=(0,0,r)$, and then have to compute the surface area of the part of the large sphere $S_t:\ \xi^2+\eta^2+(\zeta-r)^2=t^2$ lying within the small sphere $\xi^2+\eta^2+\zeta^2=a^2$. To this end it is sufficient to draw two circles in the $(\rho,\zeta)$-half plane with $\rho:=\sqrt{\xi^2+\eta^2}\geq0$, and to do some elementary geometry. Note that the surface area of a sphere cap is equal to the height of the cap times the length of the equator.

[image]

We have to compute $$h:=\zeta_*-(r-t)={1\over2r}\bigl(a^2-(r-t)^2\bigr)\ ,$$
and then
$$F(r,t)=\int_{S_t}f(\xi,\eta,\zeta)\>{\rm d}S=2\pi t\> h\ .$$